# Random "[Errno -2] Name or service not known" errors

Tags: python, django, networking, urllib

I am populating a local database using a third party service. I have a list of urls (around 500). I am calling each url in a loop, and updating my database with the returned data. The code flow looks like this:

```
for url in urllist:
    req = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(req.read())
    req.close()

    #update the db using data here
```

Whenever I run this piece of code, the script fails at random points with the error message "Name or service not known". This doesn't have anything with the urls because the script fails at random points (i.e. at 50th iteration in one run, and at 60th iteration in another)

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I think I'd put each of these calls into their own threads. I imagine, if you're getting variable errors, it's due to your network being congested at various times.

Comment: check your proxy or firewall

Comment: These requests work synchronously, and I am closing each request before beginning the next one. Could this still be about network congestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use a bad proxy or there are network problems you can try this:

```
for url in urllist:
    retry = 0
    while True: # retry request
        try:
            req = urllib.urlopen(url)
            resp_data = req.read() # in call read() network still processing
        except Exception as e: # TODO need more detailed handling
            if retry > 3: # 3 this is serious problem. exit
                raise e
            retry += 1 # retry
        else:
            data = json.loads()
            req.close() # not needed
            break
```

Comment: Yes, I can try this one but I want to find the reason for the problem and solve it. Any idea how can I see if it is proxy related or something else?

Comment: if you use not trusted proxy you can receive many various errors and not be able to fix them. I have a similar experience. I got 30% of the errors are 5 different types.

Comment: as hack you can add pause in 1-3 sec between requests

Comment: This approach seems to be working. I'd rather try and find the original source of the problem, but till then this will do ok. thanks