# sudden 'socket.gaierror': [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, sockets, dns, python-requests, errno

I am having the following error:

> (Url and api are made up in this example).
>   (, ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='urlICantDisplay.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /some_api/user_id/action_name (Caused by : [Errno -2] Name or service not known)",),), )

I use the same api for many users, but suddenly I start getting this error,
and from then I keep getting the error until I restart the process.

I've read this might be a congestion problem:
[Random "[Errno -2] Name or service not known" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20264953/random-errno-2-name-or-service-not-known-errors)

and pausing between calls **might** help, but this is a real time application that should not pause.

and also i would have presumed that the api would start working after a while,
I used the api again in the same process after 7 hours and still got the error.

I also read this is a dns error, but as i've said, dns works then suddenly stops working altogether.

Only restarting the process solved it.

I thought about saving the ip of the dns to stop asking the dns server to do it.
But i'm not sure if it will work or even connected.